# Limit generic type to known properties

Tags: typescript

I have a function `create` that takes a `Settings` parameter and returns a `FuncFact` object based on those settings. All the properties of the settings are optional. Based on a property of the settings the resulting funcFact should have a different shape.
This is how I accomplished this:

```
// all properties are optional
interface Settings {
    name?: string;
    usable?: boolean;
    values?: { [key: string]: string };
}

type FuncFact<S = Settings> = S extends { values?: { [key: string]: string } } ? Record<keyof S['values'], Function> : Record<never, Function>

declare function create<MySettings extends Settings>(settings?: MySettings): FuncFact<MySettings>;

const z = create({
  name: 'John',
  values: {
    up: '+1',
    down: '-1'
  },
  thisShouldMakeTSCompilerAngry: 'dummy' // I want only props of "Settings" to be possible here
});

z.up();  // this should keep working
```

However I would like the function "create" not to accept a parameter with unknown properties like `thisShouldMakeTSCompilerAngry`. See [REPL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEEMBtNAHAnA9rApvALgSxQZwvFUZLRAOygChNT00AzcAY0IGUV0tSBzPAbwtCDQ5ALYoA-AC5QOdPGpcA3AKEBXHOABGkCdM2JEO8KWVDQANyircU0L1ABtANYoAntNnzuAXQ9yFoAC%20yoEUFOiuqKAAYqqkjNFM6AA8LKAAvKBsHAo4AHwZWaAoAB60pAAmfBZWNtL2zm5%20Xly%20Mv7cQV3ioABKKIyI8BXJLq6IdFkOAOSWkNY4094ANDFxjCSkBdL9g8PJpCjmaKux8Zt5YRUDkOAEoHTrm6CMBOC0yQCyrtmcPMVlFCVPC-XJ5AAUOHYfxwtm%20oO4OAAlNIzgkkl8ftCwcoKINSLJQAAvQqvFDvFDg-iCUQoaTTABSiAAFqRpssVHMFvUVIJVLB6QBqACM7N5oAqiAA7qR6QBaUUqQIcwToZmYHAsZmIVSQCqfcAuAAqLAAwogRLBMDp4ABBbjwdygaYVVQiESuaagECgTCgKXGdBEUiQVxwJCwPATUAAIgRPBjoHQiFAmkIsEQOBwmG0hGZaBQFECSNxRIAdPzwSWKEA).
I think "create" needs to be generic and cannot simply take a parameter of type Settings because the type Settings can never extend `{ values?: { [key: string]: string } }`.
I thought that maybe I somehow should assert that keyof MySettings extends keyof Settings but not sure if that's the right thing to do or how to accomplish it.

Comment: If you don't want additional properties, why let it _extend_ Settings?

Comment: So that this comparison `S extends { values?: { [key: string]: string } } ?` yields the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for can be accomplished by making the type of `values` in `Settings` generic, and making `create` generic in (on?) that type, rather than making `create` treat the entire `Settings` type as generic. That way, excess property checks apply to the `Settings` type, but you can still get the specific type of `values` to use to build your result object (rather than `Record<string, ___>`).

```typescript
interface Settings<Values extends undefined | Record<string, string>> {
    name?: string;
    usable?: boolean;
    values?: Values;
}

// A type specific to the kind of functions you create, so we don't have to use `Function`
type SettingsFunction = () => void;

declare function create<Values extends undefined | Record<string, string>>(
    settings?: Settings<Values>
): Record<keyof Values, SettingsFunction>;

const z = create({
    name: "John",
    values: {
        up: "+1",
        down: "-1",
    },
    thisShouldMakeTSCompilerAngry: "dummy", // Error as desired
});

z.up(); // Works

const z2 = create({
    name: "John",
    thisShouldMakeTSCompilerAngry: "dummy", // Error as desired
});

// `z2`'s type is `Record<never, SettingsFunction>` as shown in the question for `FuncFact`
   z2
// ^? −− const z2: Record<never, SettingsFunction>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTGUBzAzgHgDU4AbAVwl2QgA9IQATKsxiGUCB5AH2QCUICAPZQG+XGCg4ANMglSQ2AHxLkAbwBQybchBwAthAD8ALjmScAbi06yuOACMSxsw6FDncENZ3IAbqQUuKbIxOSU1gC+GhoA9LHIAILIYACeAA4ouJkIwOwIKUIpABYoANagXEIwyDAsCFhCIFSpQmTICFAQcJCyuEUA7igMTQDkYMjFcH4oYEV2KAAGAGL1jSCLGmmZaBhYirirIA3ATcgAvMgAFACUF6p+QsAM1hoMgiRwXbVrpyAdXR6ECIgUo1DoEEYzFY7BAnB4-EEIjE8hk5gUyiUVxs2lwexwwTM6EwBJB4VwSg0NzMAmEonwZQgrRqYSCsmJ+zwRxOTSUr2EzQmAC8LgDupArppfHpDGYAEQAKSExRAcukOP8oNwZilvls6XlAGoAIxqjW+EYDEDygC0pvVvkiDp0YGKwFwqGKbRIDAAsnBGQAVVAAYSE+nSwGcUESiigqXlDDI+n0qTVyHiyAAolAoCJkHAqO9cMAugwNJEbq8hQA6MjpW6WDMJADqIjKuBiAokyCFACZRZ1xRBJRqZRB5UqVWbfK73Z7vX6AxBg2GI1HoLHsPHE8nU+nMzm81AC0XKKXOBWqzFM4t+4tRlRtih3chFrTkfg4TMoOz8QduXWJRNh0fs4gSAA9IwgA)

That uses `Record<never, SettingsFunction>` as the return type when `values` isn't present, which is what I think your `FuncFact` type was doing. But since `Record<never, SettingsFunction>` isn't really useful, if you like you could make it `void` instead by making the return type conditional:

```typescript
declare function create<Values extends undefined | Record<string, string>>(
    settings?: Settings<Values>
): undefined extends Values ? void : Record<keyof Values, SettingsFunction>;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTGUBzAzgHgDU4AbAVwl2QgA9IQATKsxiGUCB5AH2QCUICAPZQG+XGCg4ANMglSQ2AHxLkAbwBQybchBwAthAD8ALjmScAbi06yuOACMSxsw6FDncENZ3IAbqQUuKbIxOSU1gC+GhoA9LHIAILIYACeAA4ouJkIwOwIKUIpABYoANagXEIwyDAsCFhCIFSpQmTICFAQcJCyuEUA7igMTQDkYMjFcH4oYEV2KAAGAGL1jSCLGmmZaBhYirirIA3ATcgAvMgAFACUF6p+QsAM1hoMgiRwXbVrpyAdXR6ECIgUo1DoEEYzFY7BAnB4-EEIjE8hk5gUyiUVxs2lwexwwTM6EwBJB4VwSg0NzMLHesPhtHoTFCoKoRn8Ty4ZgEwlE+DKEFaNTCQVkxP2eCOJyaSlewmaEwAXhcAd1IFdNL49IYzAAiABSQmKIF10hx-lZZk1vls6T1AGoAIym82+EYDEB6gC0zrNvkifp0YGKwFwqGKbRIDAAsnABQAVVAAYSE+nSwGcUESiigqT1DDI+n0qVNyHiyAAolAoCJkHAqO9cMAugwNJEbq9FQA6MjpW6WMsJADqIjKuBi8okyEVACYVZ01RANebtRA9YbjS7fMHQ+HIzG4xBEym0xnoNnsLn84Xi6Xy1Wa1A6w3KM3OG2OzFy4tZ4tRlRthQUNkEWR5nk2HRZziBIAD0jCAA)

---

A couple of side notes:

- I've used `Record<string, string>` instead of `{ [key: string]: string }` just because `Record` provides a specific idiom for it (they're the same thing).
- I've used a specific function type instead of `Function` because `Function` is *untyped*. From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function):

  > This is an *untyped* function call and is generally best avoided because of the unsafe `any` return type.

  Also, using a specific function type provides a better developer experience at the call site. You can say exactly what arguments are expected, what it returns (or that its return value shouldn't be used [`void`]), etc.